# straights algorithm in yahtzee

Tags: java, algorithm

For a school assignment we are working on implementing the yahtzee game in java, but I am having some problems with making algorithms for the straights (small and large straight, which means 4/5 consecutive numbers for a small straight and 5/5 for a large).

I have made one algorithm that I believe should be working, but in reality it always puts out 0 so I should be missing something:

```
private void straights(int category) {
    Arrays.sort(dices);
    int nonConsecCount = 0;
    for(int currDice = 0; currDice < N_DICE - 2; currDice++) {
        if(dices[currDice] != dices[currDice + 1] + 1) {
            nonConsecCount++;
        }
    }
    if(nonConsecCount == 0 && category == LARGE_STRAIGHT) {
        score[currPlayer - 1][category - 1] = 40;
        display.updateScorecard(category, currPlayer, 40);
    } else if(nonConsecCount <= 1 && category == SMALL_STRAIGHT) {
        score[currPlayer - 1][category - 1] = 30;
        display.updateScorecard(category, currPlayer, 30);
    } else {
        score[currPlayer - 1][category - 1] = 0;
        display.updateScorecard(category, currPlayer, 0);
    }
}
```

`N_DICE`is equal to 5.

My theory behind this algorithm was; everytime you find a number in the (sorted) array of dicevalues that doesn't have a consecutive number as the next one, add one to the non consecutive count, and in the end check for this counter when handing out the score to the player.

Any help would we greatly appreciated!

Comment: `sort` is sorting in *ascending* order.

Comment: yes, so why shouldn't the next element of the array not be one higher to be considered consecutive?

Comment: A question why do you have N_DICE - 2 in your for loop as condition? I bet that should be N_DICE - 1

Comment: You might be right Raf, but that would mean this loop stops one loop too early and so create less nonConsecCount, so if anything it should give me more answers of 30/40 than 0.

Comment: @Perdite I have added an answer that I believe gives you the correct count value for small straight and large straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the rules of the game which I quickly skimmed through the article in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee)

```
Small Straight - Is 4 sequential dices (30 score) that is 
1,2,3,4 or 2,3,4,5 or 3,4,5,6 

Large Straight - Is 5 sequential dices (40 score) that is 
1,2,3,4,5 or 2,3,4,5,6
```

If **small straight**, then you should have a **nonConsecCount** equal to 1 because 5 - 1 is 4 and that gives us the four consecutive dices. If **large straight**, then you should have a **nonConseCount** equal to 0 because 5 - 0 gives us all five elements as consecutive.

If I understand the game correctly (taking into account the fact that I just skimmed it), you need the following modifications in your code:

- Your for loop condition should be N_DICE - 1, this would result the
  for loop to execute 4 times, one less than size of array hence, you
  are guaranteed not to get ArrayOutOfBoundException
- You need to change your if condition such that, add to the value
  of the left part of condition and then check that with value of right part of the condition that is one ahead. As a result of this, swapping you can use N_DICE - 1 instead of N_DICE - 2. N_DICE - 2 skips one array element and only checks 3 consecutive elements (not what the games rules say).

Make the following changes to your code:

```
int nonConsecCount = 0;
        for(int currDice = 0; currDice < N_DICE - 1; currDice++) {
            if(dices[currDice] + 1 != dices[currDice + 1]) {
                System.out.println("failed consecutive match!");
                nonConsecCount++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("passed consecutive match for "+ dices[currDice]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(nonConsecCount);
```

I provided the above code the following dices and got nonConsecCount as show in the comment line:

```
int[] dices = new int[]{3,4,5,1,2};
//output 0 - this is largest straight

int[] dices = new int[]{3,4,5,6,2};
//output 0 - this is largest straight too

int[] dices = new int[]{3,4,5,2,2};
//output 1 - this is smallest straight 

int[] dices = new int[]{3,4,2,2,2};
//output 2 - this is none of the two
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I'm so dumb for putting dices[currDice] != dices[currDice + 1] + 1 instead of dices[currDice] + 1 != dices[currDice + 1]. Nice catch! Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome, I learned the game too! Looks very interesting.

Comment: It's close, but there are two cases where there's a `nonConsecCount` of 1 but no small straight: `[1,2,3,5,6]` and `[1,2,4,5,6]`.